# Regular expression remove dash from tax id

Tags: regex, replace

I have a tax id of `12-1234567` and need to remove the dash/hyphen so it's all numeric 121234567
I've read different posts and tried the examples but can't get it to work.

I have used `^\d[2}\D\d[7}$` and have replace the `\D` with `\W`, `("[^0-9\\+]", "")`, etc.

I know this is simple but and I'm new to RegEx but need a little help.

Comment: Why not just replace "-" with "" (empty string)?

Comment: wouldn't you be able to do this with a simple string replace?

Comment: why do you need regex for that? just remove dash

Comment: Also, when asking regex questions, please always specify the programming language you're using (regex syntax varies between languages).

Comment: if you want to you a regex wouldn't it be the easiest to use /\d+/   ?

Comment: Hi thanks for all your comments. I'm using captiva dispathcher free form designer where I can only use regex only. I have tried to remove the dash and empty string but doesn't work. I have tested it out on http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture: `(\d{2})-(\d{7})`  replace:`$1$2` (or `\1\2` in some regex flavours).

^The most specific regex solution to your problem. Having never used the program Captiva Dispatcher, I can't tell you how to execute it. You might find more help on that front in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I'm unsure what language you're using to replace it. But this Regex `-` would match the dash. But I have to say, if you're in C# you **should** just do this:

```
var val = taxId.Replace("-", "");
```

If you're in VB.NET:

```
Dim val As String
val = taxId.Replace("-", "")
```

If you're in PHP:

```
var $val = str_replace("-", "", $taxId);
```

If you're in perl:

```
$val =~ s/-//g;
```

If you're in JavaScript:

```
var val = taxId.replace("-", "");
```

I mean, you could of course complicate the Regex and do something like this:

```
\d{2}(-)\d{7}
```

and the `-` would be in the group. But again, this isn't really a job for Regex.

Comment: Nice and clear, shows some differences between languages.. go perl!

Comment: Hi Michael... As I mentioned above I'm not writing in a specific lang as I can only use RegEx.

Comment: @mtgbanker, Regex has to be applied in some language. However, I gave you two Regex patterns. Both will match the `-`.

Answer (score 1):

```
onlyNumbersVar = Regex.Replace(taxVariable, "[^0-9]", "")
```